# Is it safe to ground electrical appliance?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have a large lamp with a metal frame which is not grounded(which I thought is a legal requirement for metal framed appliances in my country, but perhaps not).

Is there any risk if I swap out the 2 core cable with one that contains an earth, and ground the frame?

Am I'm being paranoid?

Comment: I don't think I've ever _seen_ a grounded lamp in the US, but that in itself isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe?  Assuming your ground isn't faulty, yes.  But there's no need.

In order to meet code, an appliance with an ungrounded metal frame needs to be *double insulated*: that is, it needs to be designed in a way that it takes two failures for the exposed metal to become electrically live.  For example, in your lamp this could take the form of insulated wires plus a non-conductive paint on the inner surface of any metal the wires might contact if they broke.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks. One minor followup, when I rub my hand along it I can feel a slight buzz/friction, which is what prompted the post in the first place. Still good?

Comment: I would argue that it's possible an inexpensive lamp might not have very reliable double insulation.  When it comes to power tools, etc - I would feel comfortable relying on the double insulation.  Adding a ground lead does not hurt. "Belt and suspenders".

Comment: @jasper, there are lots of things that could cause a slight buzz.  If you're not feeling any sort of tingle or shock, I wouldn't worry.